# basic_filebuf. Many strange text in output file

Tags: c++, std

1) I have this code

```
//... many code below
      std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > streamIn;
      streamIn.open("file.txt", std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::out);
      streamIn.sputn("Hello", 5);
//...
```

But in file.txt I see many many strange text. Not only Hello. This file also contaqins all my records from DB! I don't know why

2) Can I use **std::basic_filebuf** without file? Like **std::basic_stringbuf**

**Solution for 1) is found**

```
// ...
    std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > streamIn;
    streamIn.open("file.txt", std::ios_base::out);
    streamIn.sputn(responce.c_str(), responce.size());
    streamIn.close();

    streamIn.open("file.txt", std::ios_base::in);
//...
```

Comment: So the output file starts with "Hello" but has extra text behind that? Are you closing the file properly?

Comment: I haven't text "Hello" in my file! Only records from DB :(

Comment: I have streamIn.close();

Comment: Hm. Sorry then. Ehm, are you absolutely, positively sure that file.txt doesn't get overwritten later?

Comment: Solution for 1) I found. Any ideas about 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzf8k3z8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), basic_filebuf is a basic_streambuf which interacts with a file.

So no, I don't think you can use it without a file.

What you may want to do is have a basic_streambuf instead, and you control whether you want it to be a file (using basic_filebuf) or a string (using basic_stringbuf).